# Linq creates invalid SQL command

Tags: c#, linq, mariadb

I'm trying to create a simple linq select but linq translate my command to invalid sql. What can be wrong?

linq:

```
var result = (from depVer in DbContext.DependencyVersions
                      join libDep in DbContext.LibraryDependencies on depVer.Id equals libDep.DependencyVersionId
                      select depVer);
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`Discriminator`, 
`Extent1`.`id_dependency_versions`, 
`Extent1`.`id_dependencies`, 
`Extent1`.`version`, 
`Extent1`.`created`, 
`Extent1`.`description`, 
`Extent1`.`id_user`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`
FROM `dependency_versions` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `library_dependencies` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`id_dependency_versions` = `Extent2`.`id_dependency_versions`
 WHERE (`Extent1`.`Discriminator` = @gp1) OR (`Extent1`.`Discriminator` = @gp2)
```

But `DependencyVersions` does not has column Discriminator or Name. I am really confused.

EDIT:
 I think I found the reason. I have object which inherits from DependencyVersions object. But I do not understand why the linq is translated to the invalid select or why inherited object affects the SQL. Why is this happening?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please edit this into the question!

Comment: If you have inheritance, EF will implement TPH inheritance and assume a discriminator column.